# after installed editor(kindeditor) alert box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

after I installed an opensource WYSIWYG, which is "Kindeditor"
my alert box is not working, even I fill nothing,

I tried delete those code, still not working, I think I missed something, but just cannot found out, please help!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#btn").live('click',function(event){

        var msg = "all the fields are required!";

        //get Kindeditor data
        html = editor.html();
        editor.sync();

        if ($("#title").val()=="" || $("#content").val()=='' ||
            $("#file").val()=='' || $("#tag").val()=='')
        {
            alert(error);
            return false;
        } else{
            $("#btn").html('<img src="images/loader.gif">');

            $.post("post.php",$('#Form').serialize(),function(data){
                if(data['status'] == 1){
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
                    $('input').val("");
                    $('select').val("");
                    $('textarea').val("");
                    $(".showCover").hide();
                    $("#message_hide").hide().html(
                      '<div id="message">Added!</div>'
                    ).fadeIn(1000);
                    $("#btn").html(
                      '<input type="submit" value="Save" 
                       class="btn" id="btn" style="margin:0px 0 0 0px !important;">'
                    );
                    KindEditor.instances[0].html('');
                }   
            },"json");
            return false;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a javascript error in your console?

Comment: use pattern or an accurate datatype for form validation!, jquery live is obsolete use .bind instead

Comment: oh, thanks bro. I think I found out the problem.
 alert(error);  should be  alert(msg);